# What is the difference between an AD cmdlets and a powershell command?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is AD commandlet(for example : Get-ADUser) a powershell command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `Get-ADUser` is a PowerShell cmdlet, it is part of the [Active Directory module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx). The difference between a cmdlet from a module and a default built-in cmdlet like `get-help` is that you must import extra modules to get the extra cmdlets. See [Importing Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more.

`Import-Module ActiveDirectory`

Comment: And in V3 and V4, PowerShell will automatically import a module when you first use a command defined in that module.  Unless you have $PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference set to 'None'.